# the usage of the phrase 'be axed'

Tags: phrases, word-usage

According to Dictionary.com, one of the meanings of the word 'ax' is...

> '(informal) to dismiss, restrict, or destroy brutally'

(http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ax?s=t)

> Labor reforms should be accelerated so that the younger generation can find work, and regulations must be axed so that companies will be encouraged to make new investments.

I quoted this sentence from the newspaper article in the [Korea JoongAng Daily](http://koreajoongangdaily.joins.com/news/article/Article.aspx?aid=3009722), and I want to know if it is fine to use the phrase "be axed" in formal essay writing.

Comment: Pretty bad example. You have to use "revised" or "changed" rather than "ax". [The usage is not informal, but misplaced](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ax). For example, the boss will ax anyone who leaks company secrets

Comment: A better cutting word here is *pruned*.   Perhaps the author meant "relaxed."  Formal or not, this sentence represents a terrible idea, and I'm canceling my subscription to the *Korea JoongAng Daily*.

Comment: I would write "drastic deregulation must be implemented" if I were the reporter or translator.

Comment: **Axed** in American English, when applied to laws and regulations, means "gotten rid of, repealed, lifted, abolished" not tweaked or pruned or adjusted.

Comment: In British English also. It is a phrased often used by those sections of the British press who favour deregulation. Meanwhile their opponents on the left bemoan the axing of public services.

Comment: @mikeagg I don't think there are people who can't understand the meaning. Regulations are a set of good and bad rules that affect younger people positively or negatively. In that sense, "axed' doesn't seem to fit there.

Comment: Of course, one might wonder if someone is being "axed" a question -- it's a common mispronunciation of "asked".  But in the US "axed" is often used for "fired" or "laid off", or for the complete elimination (or at least very severe cuts) of some law or government program.  Never really seen is used for more moderate "pruning".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the informality, I'd be much more concerned that 'axing' is widely seen as an [emotive](http://study.com/academy/lesson/emotive-language-definition-effects-examples.html) word.

This may or may not be your intention, but (unless you're actually pointing out some act of provocation) I'd avoid it if possible in a 'formal' essay context. I'd suggest that Regulations be 'lifted' or 'removed' instead. If you want a slightly more persuasive term, try 'eased'.

Answer (score -1):

"Axed" is not a formal word, but it is widely used in journalism. [Here is one example among millions.](http://www.theguardian.com/media/2015/may/29/mx-commuter-newspaper-axed-by-news-corp-as-readers-turn-to-mobiles-instead) It is also somewhat emotive. I would avoid using it in a formal essay, but it's fine in everyday speech or less formal writing.

Possible substitutes would include "cut" or "removed", or any synonym of them.